# How to use rowspan in MVC-Razor, without javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-table

How can I merge cells in a table using rowspan inside a Razor view?

- Without using javascript/jQuery.
- The table's source is an IEnumerable.
- Some of the items in the source will have the same value in a certain field and those are the one we want to merge in one cell.
- We don't know how many times a given value is repeated.

The resulting HTML should be something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Column 1 row 1</td>
        <td>Column 2 row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 2 row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Column 1 row 3</td>
        <td>Column 2 row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 2 row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 2 row 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT to add the data source and desired result:

The data source may be something like Products with Categories. Ex:

### Categories

- Electronics
- Groceries

### Products

- Laptop (Electronics)
- iPod (Electronics)
- TV (Electronics)
- Coffee (Groceries)
- Cookies (Groceries)

### The result

```
╔═════════════╦════════╗
║ Electronics ║ Laptop ║
║             ║ iPod   ║
║             ║ TV     ║
╠═════════════╬════════╣
║ Groceries   ║ Coffee ║
║             ║ Cookies║ 
╚═════════════╩════════╝
```

The only way I have in mind is using Linq to count how many times a value is on the list, but I wanted to know if someone have a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an interesting challenge. Are you always merging on the same field? Maybe .GroupBy() ?

Comment: @jkoreska: Yes, always the same field. I don't think a group by would help. I'll edit the question to add the data source.

Comment: GroupBy and a Select should make it, the problem I see is at the time of doing the dynamic rowspan. Did you solve it?

Comment: I miss understood the first comment, I think a group by will do. At the end I did something different: a new row with the category name every time the value changes. The row also has a check box to allow the user to select all rows in the category. I think is better that way.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Movie</th>
        <th>Person</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var byMovies in elements.GroupBy(x => x.Movie)
                                      .OrderBy(movie => movie.Key.Name))
    {
        var secondRowOrHigher = false;
        @:<tr>
        @:<td rowspan="@byMovies.Count()">@byMovies.Key.Name</td>

        foreach (var ticket in byMovies.OrderBy(x => x.Person.Name))
        {
            if (secondRowOrHigher)
            {
                @:<tr>
            }
            secondRowOrHigher = true;

            <td>@ticket.Person.Name</td>
            @:</tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

and classes just to have a picture

```
public class TicketInfo
{
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```